# Firefox and Chrome shows different file size for the same compressed HTML page

Tags: performance, gzip

While checking a large e-commerce site, I saw different sizes for the compressed html of same page.

The website is https://www.trendyol.com

Chrome says it is  17.6 KB compressed and 75.8KB uncompressed. [image]

Firefox says 65.5KB compressed size.[image]

The compression is gzip. And when you download content from Chrome or Wget, it is roughly 270KB uncompressed.

And I checked the site from webpagetest.org, and it says 45KB compressed size. [image]

I see they use Express framework, and Express framework is using gzip for compression. But why there are too many different numbers?